# parsing json object to android string

Tags: java, android, json

I have tried to parse a JSON object by lot of ways but can't figure out how to parse that.

**This is my json string:**

```
 {
  "JSONDataResult":

        {"Messages":
                   [{ "Id":"0",
                      "Category":"Sport",
                      "Title":"It's a goal",
                      "Content":"sport content"
                    }]
        }
 }
```

I tried this:

```
        JSONArray arr = result.getJSONArray("Messages\\");
        for (int j = 0; i < arr.length(); j++)
        {
            String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("post_id");
            Id = result.getString("Id\\");
            Title = result.getString("Title\\");
            Content = result.getString("Content\\");   
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: What is the use of these slash \\ ??

Comment: Is that a json coming from api or a static string, api wont return '\' in result.

Answer (score 1):

there must be a lot of answers out there but this is the one i did.
guess we have a String coming from server or getting it from android cache where you stored before..

```
String listdata = "some kind of json data, might be your sample..";
JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(listdata);
System.out.println("jsnobject: " + jsnobject);
return jsnobject.getJSONArray("Messages");
```

or you already have the reponse as a list structured

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
       .....
}
```

First you convert it to a valid json object that a json array. where you want the list starts, Messages etc.. so that you can get each elements id, title ..
by getString in you example..

grats

Comment: this way not founding "Messages"

Answer (score 0):

Slash  is not required. You  simply do this

```
  JSONArray arr = result.getJSONArray("Messages");
    for (int j = 0; i < arr.length(); j++)
    {
        JsonObject object = arr.getJSONObject(i);
       Strng id = object .optString("Id");
      String Title = object .optString("Title");

    }
```

Comment: it fail to find "Messages"